# ignore a line in a markdown file with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-enterprise

Is there a way to ignore a text line in a markdown document from the Jekyll engine?

On the main README.md, I have a link to my generated pages url ala, 
`View the [Docs as a Website](https://gitpages.mycompany.com/myrepo/)` which links to our enterprise equivalent of github.io pages powered by Jekyll reading the /docs/ folder.

For obvious reasons, I would like to not show this on the pages site as the viewer is already there and it ends up in an endless loop if users were to keep clicking it.

Is there a way to have it show on the code-view readme.md but not on the rendered jekyll version?

Comment: Why do you present the readme on your final page?

Comment: It's an auto-published page via Jekyll reading the /docs folder of the repo.  There's little configuration available on the enterprise version my company runs.  Readme.md effectively becomes index.html.   So, if i type on the readme to click in to the pretty Jekyll'ified pretty version it still shows that on the pretty version as well which is an endless loop that doesn't make sense, so i'd like to hide it, if it's possible, with sole markdown codes.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution :

If you want Jekyll to skip processing lines (or even a single character) into the baked /_site/ output, use the Liquid `{% comment %}` tag:

```
{% comment %} 

     Character or lines for Jekyll to skip.

{% endcomment %}
```

### Example :

Before:
[Code w/o {% comment %} + HTML render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6GG6.png)

After:
[Code w/   {% comment %} + HTML render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4feu.png)

### Explanation :

If a markdown.md page has Jekyll `Front Matter` at the top, then it will be processed by Jekyll into a markdown.html page ([see Jekyll's docs for more info](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/03-front-matter/)).

Pages processed by Jekyll can contain Liquid code (specifically [Jekyll's implementation of Liquid](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/)).

Liquid features a `{% comment %}` tag. And it works for Jekyll.

[From Liquid's documentation of the comment tag](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/comment/):

> Comment
>
> Allows you to leave un-rendered code inside a Liquid template. Any
>   text within the opening and closing comment blocks will not be
>   printed, and any Liquid code within will not be executed.

If Jekyll processes your markdown.md page, it will process all Liquid statements, and will totally omit the `{% comment %}` tag + `{% endcomment %}` tag + and everything in between from the output file.

The text wrapped by a `{% comment %}` tag does not specifically need to contain Liquid for Jekyll to exclude it. Everything inside will be omitted from the output page: e.g. <html> elements, other code, plaintext, etc.

### Word of Caution :

Jekyll will still throw an error if you have improper Liquid syntax, even if it is inside a comment tag.

The following results in an error, and Jekyll will not build:

```
{% comment %} 

     Character or lines for Jekyll to skip.
     {% assign abc 

{% endcomment %}
```

To prevent this, either ensure (1) all the code inside your comment tag is valid Liquid, or (2) prevent Jekyll from evaluating the code by wrapping it inside a `{% raw %}` tag:

```
{% comment %} 
     {% raw %}

     Character or lines for Jekyll to skip.
     {% assign abc 

     {% endraw %}
{% endcomment %}
```

Then everything inside the comment will be successfully excluded from the /_site/ files Jekyll outputs.

For more information, see [Liquid's documentation of the raw tag.](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/raw/)

---

Alternatively:

If you just want to link from the site's GitHub repository 
-> to the site generated by Jekyll + GitHub Pages

1. Log in
2. Go to https://github.com/ `user-or-org` / `repository-name`
3. Click the "Edit" button (above "Clone or download" and below "Settings")
4. Add the URL to your GitHub Pages website in the 2nd text field that prompts "Website for this repository (optional)", and click "Save"
5. Remove the URL from your README.md